# Loop through fields in QGIS calculator with condition: count fields with values >0

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, loop, iteration

I have a dataset, a polygon, with several columns, let's say:

| Site | Species1 | Species2 | Species3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 | 23 | 90 |
| 2 | 73 | 20 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 70 |
| 5 | 0 | 75 | 60 |

I have different sites and data about several species, each is a % of the surface covered by that species. I wrote three sample columns with data about species but it is actually hundreds.

What I need is an `if` function that creates a 4th column adding the total amount of species present in each site, assuming that if `Speciesn=0` the species is absent and `Speciesn>0` the species is present. For each column I need something like:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "Species1" > 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

But I definitely need a loop to iterate through columns!

So the resulting column should look like this:

| Site | Species1 | Species2 | Species3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 | 23 | 90 | 3 |
| 2 | 73 | 20 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 70 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 75 | 60 | 2 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different version of the solution by @Bera that works automatically for all fields that contain the textstring `Species`, regardless if you have 3 or 3000 such fields, and filters out all other fields.

Another adavantage: because the filtering is based on Regular Expressions, you could add further filter criteria - e.g. if you have field names containing `Species` that you don't want to include (like `Species_remarks`), you could limit the selection to fields named `Species` followed by a number, changing line 6 below to `regexp_match( @element,'Species\\d')`. This will only select fields named `Species1`, `Species2`, ... `Species3875` etc.

[image]

1. Create an array of all fieldnames with [`attributes()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attributes) (creates a key:value map of all fields) and [`map_akeys()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map-akeys) (get the keys from this map as an array).
2. Filter this array to keep only fieldnames containing `Species` with [`array_filter()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-filter) and [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-match).
3. Then loop through all these fields with [`array_foreach()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-foreach)
4. Inside the loop, get the value of each fieldname, again using [`attributes()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attributes)  with [`map_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map-get). You get an array with the values of all fields that contain `Species` in their name.
5. Count how many of these values are >0 with [`array_filter()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-filter).

```
array_length(
    array_filter (
        array_foreach(
            array_filter(
                map_akeys( attributes()),
                regexp_match( @element,'Species')
            ),
            map_get(
                attributes(),
                @element
            )
        ),
        @element > 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the expression:

```
array_length(array:=
array_filter(array:=
array_foreach(array:=generate_series( 1,10,1),
expression:=attributes()[concat('Species', @element)]), expression:=@element > 0))
```

**Generate series** will generate the numbers from 1 to 10 (change 10 to the maximum of your field numbers, I only have 10).

Then **array foreach** will iterate over each number and combine Species+number (into the fieldname) and **attributes** will fetch the value of that field and create an array.

**Array filter** will extract the numbers in the array which are above 0.

Then **array length** will count the remaining elements in the array.

[image]